# noob "Duplicate instance declarations" (again)

Tags: haskell

yes...sorry this has been asked before, but usually about something so specific and complex that it in incomprehensible

with a naïve OO head...we go....

> class Animal a where
>
> class Mammal m where
>
> class Insect i where
>
> instance (Mammal m) => Animal m
>
> instance (Insect i) => Animal i

and ghc goes

Duplicate instance declarations:

```
  instance forall (k :: BOX) (m :: k). Mammal m => Animal m
  instance forall (k :: BOX) (i :: k). Insect i => Animal i
```

and you look it up...and there is a solution using witness types, that I could probably get to work BUT....I don't understand what the problem?

allegedly the compiler matches the right hand side and bla bla...?

I don't understand....I think I'm saying...if I have a type of typeclass Dog...then its also of typeclass Animal...so if I call methods foo etc then this is how to do it (in terms of a Dog)

I'm missing something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, you're missing something. Here's how you should have defined your class hierarchy:

```
class Animal a where
class Animal a => Mammal a where
class Animal a => Insect a where
```

This is how you express superclass relationships. Instance declarations are for actually making types instances of your classes.

```
instance Animal Ant where
instance Insect Ant where
```

#### What goes wrong in the original

You wrote

```
instance (Mammal m) => Animal m

instance (Insect i) => Animal i
```

Haskell requires that there be only one instance for each class and type. Thus is determined only from the part to the right of the `=>`. So it sees two declarations for

```
instance Animal a
```

and complains. You could have

```
instance Animal (Maybe a)
```

and also

```
instance Animal Int
```

But if you have

```
instance Animal a
```

then you can't have any other instance declarations for `Animal`.

Comment: really...I'm not a complete noob...but I haven't done any Haskell for a whole...and I've not dabbled with superclasses...let me have a go

Comment: actually I still have the problem...I had the example the wrong way around...let me give a better exampe

Comment: actually....you've side stepped the answer....what IS the problem with what I've written....I understand what you've written....(naïvely) a cannot be a mammal unless its an animal....ok,,,,but what I've written is...if I have a mammal I can make an animal....I need to construct a better example