# Duplicate instance declaration using Haskell Singletons

Tags: haskell

I'm using the [Singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-3.0) and Singletons-th library and I want to be able to implement a method depending on whether its singleton has a key associated or not.

I've defined the singletons as:

```hs
singletons
  [ d|
  data Field = FieldName1
             | FieldName2
             | FieldName3
             (deriving Eq, Show)
  ]

singletons
  [ d|
     toKey FieldName1 = ""
     toKey FieldName2 = "_field_name2"
     toKey FieldName3 = "field_name3"
     
     hasKey x = toKey x == ""
  ]
```

Then, I tried using it to instantiate a class, but I'm not able to

```hs
instance S.HasKey f ~ 'False => ToPairs (Attr f) where
  toPairs x = []

instance S.HasKey f ~ 'True => ToPairs (Attr f) where
  toPairs x = [ somecode ]
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
       instance (S.HasKey f ~ 'False) => ToPairs (Attr f)
         -- Defined at src/IHaskell/Display/Widgets/Types.hs:492:10
       instance (S.HasKey f ~ 'True) => ToPairs (Attr f)
```

My goal is to be able to translate the singleton to a string, and to implement the `toPairs` method depending on if it has an empty string or not.

Comment: See the "what goes wrong in the original" part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32376231/15207568

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that. This means I have to put the type restrictions on the right of the declaration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this you can introduce a new class that is explicitly parameterised by the truth value. Here is an example file that compiles, but I don't know the specifics of your type classes so I had to use a bunch of stubs.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Attr f

type family HasKey a where
  HasKey () = 'True
  HasKey _ = 'False

class ToPairs a where
  toPairs :: a -> [b]

instance ToPairs' (HasKey f) f => ToPairs (Attr f) where
  toPairs x = toPairs' x

class hasKey ~ HasKey a => ToPairs' hasKey a where
  toPairs' :: Attr a -> [b]

instance HasKey f ~ 'False => ToPairs' 'False f where
  toPairs' x = []

instance HasKey f ~ 'True => ToPairs' 'True f where
  toPairs' x = [ undefined ]
```

Comment: Maybe the singletons library implements this in some form, but this answer worked fine!